# Отображение данных с сервера в мобильном приложении

Tags: c#, gridview

Уже есть мобильное приложение, главная цель которого – это информирование людей о новых картинках, распределённых в тематических каталогах. Размер общего количества картинок может быть большим (от 20 до 100 Gb). Каталоги с картинками будут  на отдалённом сервере и автоматически обновляться на гаджетах пользователей.

Задача:
надо найти способ этих каталогов с картинками в мобильном приложении, при этом надо учесть корректное отображение и оптимизацию работы, чтобы приложение не зависало при открытии большого количества изображений.
Примечание:

Каталог с картинками будет загружать на сервер владелец (не программист, а обычный пользователь) *apk-файла (приложения). Картинки с каталогами должны отображаться в приложении на гаджетах автоматически с сервера. Желательна реализация на C# и отображение картинок методом GridView.

Comment: Вы хотите положить 100Г картинок на мобильный телефон пользователя? о_О

Comment: а минимальный ПРИБЛИЗИТЕЛЬНЫЙ объём, который советуете? Да и не на сам телефон вешать большоё объём, а на сервер, а телефон уже будет кэшировать только то, что захочет пользователь телефона.
А по сути реализации отображения с сервера что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Я могу вытесняющий кэш посоветовать. Вы можете хранить картинки, а при достижении общего размера P удалять ту, к которой не обращались дольше всего времени. Вопрос: чему же равен P? Тут я бы посоветовал брать как функцию из min([свободное место]*0.1, 1Gb). И храните фото вот тут - cacheDir ( http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir() ), в папке для кэша.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут можно посоветовать делать примерно так же, как делают соц. сети:

1. Для каждого пользователя сервер сможет сам придумать ленту обновлений (ниже опишу варианты)
2. Клиент получает список id-шников картинок, причем id должен содержать путь (или пути) хранения.
3. При открытии клиента происходит запрос к серверу в виде "дай мне 100 последних новостей, начиная с первой", клиент получает список id шников.
4. Клиент показывает Grid с кучей картинок, каждая из которых имеет текст "загрузка" (или вместо картинки можно text использовать, неважно)
5. Клиент запускает все картинки в порядке новости (т.е. новейшие раньше) в M потоков (чтобы вместо того, чтобы иметь 10% загруженности каждой картинки получить 10% загруженных картинок). M надо подбирать уже тестами, все зависит от размера данных и скоростей. Все загрузки идут в фоновом потоке, после окончания она отправляется на UI в соответствующее поле.
6. С точки зрения пользователя, картинки постепенно начинают появляться, одна за одной.

Как сделать сервер:
 1. Если у Вас база данных, и все идентификаторы хранятся там (но не картинки), то надо сделать просто select ... order by priority, где приоритет можно посчитать, например, как "новизна" + "теги, которые нравятся пользователю" + "близость к пользователю". 
 2. Если все пользователи получают один и тот же список обновлений, то можно просто хранить txt/xml/json на сервере и иногда обновлять его. В нем должны быть записаны эти самые id в хронологическом порядке. А сервер просто выдает нужные строки.

Как составить id:
 1. Пусть у нас N контент серверов. Каждая картинка хранится на M из них и имеет свой guid (защита от перебора).
 2. Тогда id - наш guid и список серверов. То есть чтобы загрузить картинку, клиент должен обратиться на url вида https://{server}/images/{guid}.jpg
 3. В идеале, если сервер не ответил, то надо попробовать другой. Ну и конечно, тоже в идеале, делать запросы к разным серверам, чтобы сбалансировать нагрузку.

Как залить картинки:
 1. Создаем отдельное приложение/web страничку.
 2. Пользователь выбирает картинки, нажимает загрузить.
 3. Для каждой картинки: пользователь идет в базу, определяется со списком серверов, копирует на каждвй картинку по сетевой шаре, записывает транзакцию в базу.

Это самая простая реализация, которую, конечно, можно расширять. Здесь у клиента всё хранится в памяти, сервер не особо заботится об авторизациях и т.д. Однако, как я понял, это то, что Вам надо.

Про более детальную реализацию: что конкретно интересует? Как скомпановать картинки "квадратиками"? Или как запрашивать их у сервера?

Comment: Большое спасибо за отклик!!! Но остались еще вопросы.